# Find, group by and count relationships in Neo4J using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have 2 sets of labels in neo4j 3.03:-

```
INTERACTIONS

uidpid  100000060085836_170782808933_10154454374183934
name    Dean Hohaia
postid  170782808933_10154454374183934
pageid  170782808933
userid  100000060085836

POSTS

shares      0
comments    0
postid      100129044360_100138063361365
pageid      100129044360
type        link
createdtime 2010-03-30 00:43:23
pagename    Study in New Zealand
likes       4
```

I have  a relationship called LIKES which has been created likes this:-

```
MATCH (i:interactions),(p:posts)
WHERE i.userid = p.userid
CREATE (i)-[:likes]->(p)
```

which look like this:

```
uidpid  613637235481924_125251397514429_1000501533322740
name    Toth Mariann
postid  125251397514429_1000501533322740
pageid  125251397514429
userid  613637235481924
```

same as interactions basically.

I need to find a way to create a query that shows:-

for each pagename in posts, show count of userid interactions by pagename:-

```
Source Pagename  Matched Pagename   Userids count #
Air New Zealand  Rialto Channel     12494
Air New Zealand  RNZ                2979
Air New Zealand  SKY TV             4651
```

In essence - for each pagename in posts, show the count of all other pages that each user has engaged with.

Do I need to create any other relationships to achieve this?

Here's the exact, example data I'm using as CSV's https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/37e89c65f029344a2205ca717f04b6fe20161024051807/0d4ab3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you mentioned we connect the interactions and the posts based on the `postid` (1).

```
MATCH (i:interactions), (p:posts)
WHERE i.postid = p.postid
CREATE (i)-[:likes]->(p)
```

Then we create a node for each user (2):

```
MATCH (i:interactions)
WITH DISTINCT i.userid AS userid
CREATE (u:user {userid: userid})
```

And connect them to the interactions (3):

```
MATCH (u:user), (i:interactions)
WHERE u.userid = i.userid
CREATE (u)-[:performed]->(i)
```

It's possible to perform these two `CREATE` operations (2 and 3) with a single `MERGE` but the performance seems to be much worse - not sure why.

```
MATCH (i:interactions)
MERGE (u:users {userid: i.userid})-[:performed]->(i)
```

Having created the `likes` and `performed` relationships, we can now formulate the query like this (4):

```
MATCH (source:posts)<-[:likes]-(:interactions)<-[:performed]-(:users)-[:performed]->(:interactions)-[:likes]->(matched:posts)
RETURN source.pagename, matched.pagename, COUNT(matched)
LIMIT 10
```

Warning: this took two minutes to run on my laptop (late-2011 quad-core i7 CPU + SSD).

The query starts from a post (`source`), and navigates through `likes` and `performed` edges to each user that performed the interaction. It then navigates to those users' other interactions (again, through `likes` and `performed` edges), which ends in a node representing a post (`matched`). The number of `matched` nodes is aggregated with the [`COUNT` method](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_count) and returned, along with the pagename properties.

A related suggestion: label names should start with an uppercase letter and should be singular, i.e. `Post`, `Interaction` and `User`.

Comment: Hi @szarnyasg - here's the link to the data, your example worked but not with my data. Thanks for trying - any help would be greatly appreciated https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/37e89c65f029344a2205ca717f04b6fe20161024051807/0d4ab3

Comment: I managed to import the data to an empty database with this (careful - it loads to `graph.db`) `bin/neo4j-import --into data/databases/graph.db --id-type string --nodes:interactions import/neo_ilab_people.csv --nodes:posts import/neo_posts.csv`. However, there is no `userid` in posts: `head -n 1 import/neo_posts.csv` displays: `"pageid","pagename","postid","type","createdtime","likes","comments","shares"`. This would be used by the query that creates the `likes` relationships.

Comment: Thanks @szarnyasg, the relationship between posts and interactions is via postid. So the query I'm looking for (sent to you in a linkedin message) is get count of all user ids for a page (air New Zealand) AND a list of all other pages these userids have engaged with - does that make sense?

Comment: I changed the relationship (my bad) to postid = postid like you did but I can't make the query work with the data in wetransfer :-(

Comment: perfect - it's almost there but I guess this where I start learning - thanks so much for your help. Can you explain exactly how this works and what each step is doing please?

Comment: You're welcome. I added some clarification to the answer.